# Salesforce Test class getting System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '[' at the beginning of List/Set Error

Tags: apex

I have written a trigger and handler class (which uses a future method) and it works well. I am really struggling to write the test class for it. My first problem is that the code coverage is high (before tweaks it was 0% in the handler class). After tweaking, I am getting the following error:
System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '[' at the beginning of List/Set
I am not sure how to solve this and I am a pretty new dev so not sure what to do next . Can someone please help?
Here is my code:
Trigger:

```
trigger AccountTriggerKeepAcctTeam on Account (before update) {
    List<AccountTeamMember> listAcc = [SELECT Id, AccountAccessLevel, AccountId, CaseAccessLevel, UserId, ContactAccessLevel, OpportunityAccessLevel, TeamMemberRole, PhotoUrl, Title FROM AccountTeamMember Where AccountId in : Trigger.new AND TeamMemberRole != 'Account Executive']; 
    for(Account acc: Trigger.new){
        Account oldAccount = Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id);
        if(acc.OwnerId != oldAccount.OwnerId){
            system.debug('AccountTeamMember records: '+(JSON.serialize(listAcc))); 
            String str = JSON.serialize(listAcc); 
             //delete team member records if required
            AccountTriggerKeepAcctTeamHandler.retainOldTeamMemberOnOwnerChange(str);   
        }
    }
    
}
```

Handler:

```
public class AccountTriggerKeepAcctTeamHandler {
    @future
    public static void retainOldTeamMemberOnOwnerChange(String str){
        system.debug('Future call '+str); 
        List<AccountTeamMember> newlistAcc = (List<AccountTeamMember>) JSON.deserialize(str,List<AccountTeamMember>.class);
        for(AccountTeamMember objAccTeamMember : newlistAcc){
            objAccTeamMember.Id= null;
        }
        system.debug('Account records to insert'+(JSON.serialize(newlistAcc)));
        Upsert newlistAcc;
     }
}
```

Test class:

```
@isTest
public class AccountTriggerKeepAcctTeamTest {
    //@TestSetup
    
    static testMethod void AcctOwnerChange(){
        List<User> userList = TestDataFactory.createUser(true, 2);
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator']; 
        User u1 = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg1.com', 
            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
            LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
            TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser@testorg01.com');
        
        insert u1;

        User u2 = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg2.com', 
            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing2', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
            LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
            TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser@testorg92.com');
        
        insert u2;

        System.runAs(u1){
            Allowed_Account_Owner_Change__c setting = new Allowed_Account_Owner_Change__c();
            setting.Allowed_to_change_Account_Owner__c = true;
            insert setting;
            fferpcore__ExchangeRateGroup__c exrg = new fferpcore__ExchangeRateGroup__c(CurrencyISOCode = 'USD', fferpcore__DefaultCurrency__c = 'USD - U.S. Dollar', Name = 'FF Shared Test Group', fferpcore__SelectedCurrencies__c = 'USD - U.S. Dollar');
            insert exrg;
            c2g__codaCompany__c company = new c2g__codaCompany__c();
            company.Name = 'ApexTestCompany';
            company.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.c2g__codaCompany__c.RecordTypeInfosByName.get('SUT').RecordTypeId;
            insert company;
            company.c2g__ExchangeRateGroup__c = exrg.Id;
            update company;

            Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test Acc2', NumberOfEmployees = 500);//TestDataFactory.createAccountwithCurrencyMaster(true);
            acc.OwnerId = userinfo.getUserId();
            insert acc;
            
            AccountTeamMember accTeam   = new AccountTeamMember();
            accTeam.UserId                  =  acc.OwnerId;
            accTeam.AccountAccessLevel  =  'Read';
            accTeam.AccountId           =  acc.Id;
            insert accTeam;
            
            System.debug('## User '+userinfo.getUserName());
            //create opportunity

            
        //}        

   // }
    
  //  static testMethod void testAcctOwnerChange(){
       // User u = [Select id, LastName from User where LastName = 'Testing2'];
       // Account acc = [Select id, OwnerId from Account Limit 1];
       Test.startTest();
        acc.OwnerId = u2.id;
        update acc;
        AccountTriggerKeepAcctTeamHandler.retainOldTeamMemberOnOwnerChange(JSON.serialize(acc));
        //System.assertEquals(accTeam.UserId,u2.Id);
        Test.stopTest();
        //AccountTeamMember atm = [Select userId,AccountId, AccountAccessLevel from AccountTeamMember where AccountId =: acc.Id];
        
    }
    
    

}
```

Can someone please help? I am a beginner apex dev

Trigger Attempt for Alin's test class:

```
trigger AccountTriggerKeepAcctTeam on Account (before update) {
    Set<Id> accteammbrId = new Set<Id>();
    List<AccountTeamMember> listAcc = [SELECT Id, AccountAccessLevel, AccountId, CaseAccessLevel, UserId, ContactAccessLevel, OpportunityAccessLevel, TeamMemberRole, PhotoUrl, Title FROM AccountTeamMember Where AccountId in : Trigger.new AND TeamMemberRole != 'Account Executive']; 
    for(Account acc: Trigger.new){
        Account oldAccount = Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id);
        if(acc.OwnerId != oldAccount.OwnerId){
            //system.debug('AccountTeamMember records: '+(JSON.serialize(listAcc))); 
            //String str = JSON.serialize(listAcc); 
            for(AccountTeamMember actmbr : listAcc){
                accteammbrId.add(actmbr.Id);
            }
            
             //delete team member records if required
            AccountTriggerKeepAcctTeamHandler.retainOldTeamMemberOnOwnerChange(accteammbrId);   
        }
    }
    
}

public class AccountTriggerKeepAcctTeamHandler {
    @future
    public static void retainOldTeamMemberOnOwnerChange(Set<Id> AccteambrId){
        List<AccountTeamMember> newlistAcc = [SELECT Id, AccountAccessLevel, AccountId, CaseAccessLevel, UserId, ContactAccessLevel, OpportunityAccessLevel, TeamMemberRole, PhotoUrl, Title FROM AccountTeamMember Where AccountId in :AccteambrId];
        //system.debug('Future call '+str); 
        //List<AccountTeamMember> newlistAcc = (List<AccountTeamMember>) JSON.deserialize(str,List<AccountTeamMember>.class);
        for(AccountTeamMember objAccTeamMember : newlistAcc){
            objAccTeamMember.Id= null;
        }
        //system.debug('Account records to insert'+(JSON.serialize(newlistAcc)));
        system.debug('Account records to insert' + newlistAcc);
        Upsert newlistAcc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have to serialize the list in the first place.
Change your retainOldTeamMemberOnOwnerChange to accept a List as parameter and don't use the JSON at all.
Then in your test class you create an account, assign an account team to it and change the owner. After that you will query the List of associated AccountTeamMember and assert it with regards to the AccountTeamMember before the ownership of the account was changed.
If it's not clear enough I can give you a code example, but I think the exercise will be good for you.

Edit: I see. My bad. This is what I use for test coverage. I can also provide code sample from the trigger  if needed.

Trigger:

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before update, After Update) {
    if(trigger.isBefore){
        if(trigger.isUpdate){
            AccountTriggerHandler.retainAccountTeam(trigger.new, trigger.oldMap);
        }
    }
}
```

Handler:

```
public class AccountTriggerHandler {
    public static void retainAccountTeam(List<Account> newList, Map<Id, Account> oldMap) {
        Set<Id> accountsWithNewOwners = new Set<Id>();
        for(Account acc : newList){
            if(acc.OwnerId != oldMap.get(acc.Id).OwnerId){
                accountsWithNewOwners.add(acc.Id);
            }
        }
        if(accountsWithNewOwners.size() > 0){
            List<AccountTeamMember> listAcc = [SELECT Id, AccountAccessLevel, AccountId, CaseAccessLevel, UserId, ContactAccessLevel, OpportunityAccessLevel, TeamMemberRole, PhotoUrl, Title FROM AccountTeamMember WHERE AccountId IN :accountsWithNewOwners]; 
            system.debug('AccountTeamMember records: '+(JSON.serialize(listAcc))); 
            String str = JSON.serialize(listAcc); 
            // delete team member records if required
            retainOldTeamMemberOnOwnerChange(str); 
        }
    }

    //Before Update calls the future method that basically reinserts the Account Team member records. You can also consider deleting the Account Team Member records before calling the future method. 
    @future
    public static void retainOldTeamMemberOnOwnerChange(String str){
        system.debug('Future call '+str); 
        List<AccountTeamMember> newlistAcc = (List<AccountTeamMember>) JSON.deserialize(str,List<AccountTeamMember>.class);
        for(AccountTeamMember objAccTeamMember : newlistAcc){
            objAccTeamMember.Id= null;
        }
        system.debug('Account records to insert'+(JSON.serialize(newlistAcc)));
        Upsert newlistAcc;
    }
}
```

Test method:

```
static testMethod void test_retainAccountTeam(){
    Id mhbkRTId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('MHBK').getRecordTypeId();
    Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator']; 
    User u = new User(
        Alias = 'rivacon', 
        Email = 'rivaConnector@testorg.com', 
        EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8', 
        LastName = 'Connector', 
        FirstName = 'Riva', 
        LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US', 
        LocaleSidKey = 'en_US', 
        ProfileId = p.Id, 
        TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles', 
        UserName = 'rivaConnector@testorg.com');
    insert u;

    User u2 = new User(
        Alias = 'updated', 
        Email = 'rivaConnector@testorg.com', 
        EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8', 
        LastName = 'Connector', 
        FirstName = 'Riva2', 
        LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US', 
        LocaleSidKey = 'en_US', 
        ProfileId = p.Id, 
        TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles', 
        UserName = 'rivaConnector2@testorg.com');
    insert u2;
    
    system.runAs(u){
        Account acc = new Account(RecordTypeId = mhbkRTId,Name = 'test',Branch__c='London',Industry='Banking',Year_Founded__c='1900',BillingStreet = '1 Long Rd',BillingCity = 'City',CurrencyIsoCode = 'GBP');
        insert acc;
            
        AccountTeamMember atm = new AccountTeamMember();
        atm.AccountId =  acc.Id;
        //atm.Name ='Test ATM';
        atm.TeamMemberRole = 'Sales Assistant';
        atm.UserId = u.Id;
        insert atm;

        Test.startTest();
        acc.OwnerId = u2.Id;
        update acc;
        Test.stopTest();

        System.debug('usr1 ' + u.id);
        System.debug('usr2 ' + u2.id);
        Account updatedAccount = [SELECT OwnerId FROM Account WHERE Id = :acc.Id];
        system.assertEquals(u2.Id, updatedAccount.OwnerId);

        List<AccountTeamMember> teamMembers = [SELECT Id, AccountAccessLevel, AccountId, UserId, TeamMemberRole, Title FROM AccountTeamMember WHERE AccountId = :acc.Id];
        system.assertEquals(1, teamMembers.size());
        system.assertEquals(teamMembers[0].TeamMemberRole, atm.TeamMemberRole);
    }
```

Comment: but this the handler has a future method. I can not pass a list of accounts to a future method which is why I serialized it

Comment: @coder12344567 I have edited the initial response. Hope that helps

Comment: Hi Alin, can you please provide your trigger/handler code too. Did you still keep the future method? I would like to keep the future so that I can avoid soql 101 errors in our org. Just FYI, what the code is doing is if the account owner changes, it keeps the account team. If it doesnt change, do nothing

Comment: I just attempted the trigger/class according to your test class. It is in the paragraph above. Although I dont think it is right but tried it anyways

Comment: @coder12344567 added trigger and handler class too.

Comment: Thank you Alin! I will test this right now

Comment: it seems like when account owner changes, the new account owner is not being added to the team now. it just keeps the old owner to the team

Comment: Well I didn't knew of this requirement. What is your trigger supposed to do?